# AngularJS Select unique value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an order attribute in the following object.

```
var media = [{
  id:1,
  order:0,
  text:'Lala'
},
{
  id:2,
  order:1,
  text:'Lala'
}]
```

I use select as follows:

```
<div ng-repeat = "asset in media">
  <select ng-model="asset.order" ng-options="c.order as c.order for c in media">
  </select>
</div>
```

Each object has its own field. When I change order, the other field that has the same value has to be swapped. Basically, order values should be unique.

EDIT: Included jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hTwrF/1/

Comment: It is not clear what you are after. Maybe an example would help.

Comment: It seems like you have several `assets` that's you're looping through, showing that in your example and the reordering would be helpful. A fiddle via jsfiddle.net would be best

Comment: Updated with example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is entirely possible when a drop down changes call a scope method using ng-change.

Your logic will likely need to change depending on the number of assets, but this should show you enough to move on ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hTwrF/2/))

```
ng-change="swapOrder(asset)"
```

Comment: Wow ! Accepted answer ! I wonder how the OP is going to use this solution with more than 2 elements...

Comment: @ExpertSystem Agreed that it is not a 100% plug in and use solution, but it proves how to handle the change event so that the appropriate logic could get implemented, and I made note of that in the answer I provided.

Comment: You did indeed. My surprise goes to the OP that found this answer to solve the problem (unless they only have 2 items). The problem is that there is no staight-formward way to determine the previous order of the asset.

Comment: My implementation without drop downs would be move up/down buttons and use the orderBy filter. Only way I would track the previous value would be to add a new field onto the asset named like `prevOrder` for the current solution.